# How do you redirect to a page when the response keeps returning in JSON?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using [dropzone.js](http://www.dropzonejs.com/) for image uploads.

In my coffeescript js file I have the setup for dropzone:

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false

dropzone = new Dropzone('#item-form',
  maxFiles: 1
  maxFilesize: 1
  paramName: 'item[image]'
  headers: "X-CSRF-Token" : $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
  addRemoveLinks: true
  clickable: '#image-preview'
  previewsContainer: '#image-preview'
  thumbnailWidth: 200
  thumbnailHeight: 200
  parallelUploads: 100;
  autoProcessQueue: false
  uploadMultiple: false)

$('#item-submit').click (e) ->
  e.preventDefault()
  e.stopPropagation()
  if dropzone.getQueuedFiles().length > 0
    dropzone.processQueue()
  else
    $('#item-form').submit()
  return
return
```

Besides from the options, the clicking of the submit button on my form, if there is an image present, will process the image and if there's no image will submit the form anyways.

Next is my controller (relevant code):

```
  def create
    @item = current_user.items.build(item_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @item.save
        format.html { redirect_to @item, notice: 'Item was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @item }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Than my form:

```
= form_for @item, html: {id: 'item-form', class: 'form', multipart: true} do |f|
 = f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control'

    %main#image-preview
     Add a Photo
     .fallback
      = f.file_field :image, multiple: false

= f.submit 'Done', id: 'item-submit'
```

So now this setup has everything working. Before I got a `Missing Template` error because I needed to create a `show.json.erb` template and after I did that it gives me this in the log:

```
Started POST "/items" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-10-16 21:36:18 -0700
Processing by ItemsController#create as JSON
...................
   (10.7ms)  COMMIT
  Item Store (142.4ms)  {"id":12}
  Rendered items/show.json.erb (0.4ms)
Completed 201 Created in 2759ms (Views: 6.1ms | Searchkick: 142.4ms | ActiveRecord: 11.9ms)
```

So now I'm wondering when using JSON or just in this scenario all together, how do I redirect to the item show page if it keeps forcing me to use JSON?

> UPDATE

When changing my response when item is saved:

```
if @item.save
  format.html { redirect_to @item }
  format.json { redirect_to @item }
else
```

It does this:

```
Started GET "/items/13" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-10-16 22:54:29 -0700
Processing by ItemsController#show as JSON
  Parameters: {"id"=>"13"}
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
  Item Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "items".* FROM "items" WHERE "items"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 13]]
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
  Rendered items/show.json.erb (0.7ms)
Completed 200 OK in 137ms (Views: 7.5ms | ActiveRecord: 25.2ms)
```

So I believe some how I have to do a `GET` requests as HTML in order for it to do right?

> UPDATE 2

I did the following below and had to create a `create.json.erb` file as well.

```
if @item.save
  format.html { redirect_to @item }
  format.json { redirect_to item_path(@item, format: :html) } and return
else

Started POST "/items" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-10-16 23:36:13 -0700
Processing by ItemsController#create as JSON............

   (12.9ms)  COMMIT
  Item Store (426.1ms)  {"id":18}
  Rendered items/create.json.erb (19.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 3892ms.....
```

It still doesn't redirect me giving me the same results as before.

> UPDATE 3

So doing `format.json { redirect_to item_path(@item) and return}` does not redirect to the show page but processes in JSON. And doing `format.json { redirect_to item_path(@item, format: :html) and return}` leaves me with `Started GET "/items/19.html` which is wrong since you can't get a page with `.html` at the end.

> UPDATE 3

Still no luck with any variation of:

```
format.json {render :show, status: :created, location: item_url(@item, format: :html )}
```

I'm thinking I have to redirect with `window.location` which is apart of JavaScript, somewhere in my code but need to do more research. I don't care if I can get this working in `js` or `html` format as long as it works.

> UPDATE 4

Okay, so I was able to get the same behavior in a brand new test app at my GitHub here: https://github.com/justintech/dropzonetest. This one throws the `Invalid JSON response from server.` So I'm guessing that my real app does the same thing but it just glitches and passes as a complete response. weird. Feel free to check it out.

Comment: what would you like to respond with if your create_action (in `JSON` format)  succeeds?

Comment: @illusionist HTML if possible.

Comment: if you are never gonna respond with `JSON` format then you can remove all the `format.json {}` statements and make sure that all the request the client can make are in `HTML` requests

Comment: did you end up needing the js.erb file? it is not shown in the code but you mentioned it. i was able to get my v similar project working without it.

Comment: did you check that the `else` controller code was working on a fail?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Forget the format section if you want both formats to respond the same.  All you need is the redirect.  Try just `redirect_to(@item)`.

**Edit**:

I looked at your code.  I found that the following works:

items_controller.rb:

```
def create
  @item = Item.new(item_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @item.save
      format.html { redirect_to @item, notice: 'Item was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render json: @item }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

in items.coffee:

```
$(document).ready ->
  # disable auto discover
  Dropzone.autoDiscover = false

  dropzone = new Dropzone('#item-form',
    maxFiles: 1
    maxFilesize: 1
    paramName: 'item[image]'
    headers: "X-CSRF-Token" : $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    addRemoveLinks: true
    clickable: '#image-preview'
    previewsContainer: '#image-preview'
    thumbnailWidth: 200
    thumbnailHeight: 200
    parallelUploads: 100;
    autoProcessQueue: false
    uploadMultiple: false)

  $('#item-submit').click (e) ->
    e.preventDefault()
    e.stopPropagation()
    if dropzone.getQueuedFiles().length > 0
      dropzone.processQueue()
    else
      $('#item-form').submit()

  dropzone.on 'success', (file, responseText) ->
    window.location.href = '/items/' + responseText.id
```

Comment: That doesn't work. Thats what the original problem was, that's why I have to format it or something. Its something weird how Dropzone.js works.

Comment: Okay, are you sure the save is successful.  Maybe it's failing and trying to render instead.  You can change the render direction by passing it the location option.

Comment: if you look at `UPDATE 2` above it does complete the save and can access the items show page. Its just the redirecting that doesn't occur. The `dropzone.js` image area will process and than after it complete, that page stays the same.

Comment: Actually, what you were doing originally was right, so it is weird.  You can try tweaking it with this just in case:    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: item_url(@item)}

Comment: I tried changing the status to `success` and `redirect` and also the format to `html` but still no luck.

Comment: @JohnHuntington can you please help me write `dropzone.on 'failure'` in this question -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38960487/dropzone-js-not-redirecting-or-rendering-errors-properly-on-failure

Answer (score 6):

If you want to `redirect_to` the `items` `show` page which you do for your `html` format, why not just do the same for `json` format as well?:

```
  if @item.save
    format.html { redirect_to @item, notice: 'Item was successfully created.' }
    format.json { redirect_to @item, notice: 'Item was successfully created.' }
  # rest of your codes
  end
```

Comment: Thank you so far as this seems like it has me on the right track. Check out my edit to see what happens when I do as you say.

Comment: How about `redirect_to item_path(@item, format: :html)`?

Comment: This is strange. It returns `Processing by ItemsController#show as HTML
` like it should but it still stays on the same page.

Comment: can you please try: `redirect_to item_path(@item, format: :html) and return`?

Comment: That makes me have to create a `create.json.erb` which renders `Rendered items/create.json.erb`. Unless I'm not putting it in the right place. Check out my edit if you need to.

Comment: At this moment. not really sure if thats really possible. Can you please post your `routes.rb` file? I will take a look and will get back to you.

Comment: These are my routes at this gist link: https://gist.github.com/justintech/db7bfa5b494d77b7ad2d

Comment: it should be processed by the `show` action BUT not `create`.

Comment: try exactly this: `format.json { redirect_to item_path(@item, format: :html) and return}` your return wha outside the block.

Comment: I think I see the issue. Is it suppose to do this? `Started GET "/items/19.html`? With the `.html` word at the end of the link. That looks strange.

Comment: may be because we specified: `format: :html`, if you remove that, then it should be gone.

Comment: Could you please reproduce the issue in a separate project and share the github link so that we can take a look locally?

Comment: Okay, so I was able to get the same behavior in a brand new test app at my GitHub here: https://github.com/justintech/dropzonetest. This one throws the `Invalid JSON response from server.` So I'm guessing that my real app does the same thing but it just glitches and passes as complete. weird.

Comment: I tried to make it work like you want, but seems like nothing is working as exactly what you want. Try to think in a different way, try to think about the original problem again. What is your ultimate goal? What you really want to accomplish? I am sure there is a better way of doing that! You just need to attack the problem from a different angle.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking about adding the picture on a different page. Well nice try. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

FYI

> **Your sentence:**
>   `format.json { redirect_to item_path(@item, format: :html) and return}` leaves me with `Started GET "/items/19.html` which is wrong **since you can't get a page with .html at the end**.

this is not processed as you think; Rails does not look for some page like `1.html`, it passes the number `1` as `params[:id] = 1` and `html` as request format.

Since there is `.html` in the request

`format.html {}` is activated
otherwise
`format.json {}` would have been activated
if request was `/1.json`

Comment: But even though `format.html` is activated. It will still use `JSON` to submit my form. This is fine though. All I want to do is after it processes my image, go to the next page whether its possible by `HTML` or `JS`.

Comment: how is the form submitted; via `AJAX` or normal `Form submit`? ; moreover standard says that if client requests for `JSON` you have to respond with `JSON` data no matter what.

Comment: It's submitted by JSON when a images is present but if there's no image, than it will do regular HTML