# dropzone.js not redirecting or rendering errors properly on failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dropzone.js

Everything is working fine with [dropzone.js](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#events) except when a photo fails to upload.

if the form is submitted with a photo attached that is too big or the form is submitted without a photo the following happens:

In Heroku Console

> Started POST "/photos" for ...Processing by PhotosController#create as HTML
>   Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity ... method=POST path="/photos

The browser then shows example.com/photos but the screen is blank.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var dropzone;
  Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
  dropzone = new Dropzone('#dropform', {
    maxFiles: 1,
    maxFilesize: 1,
    paramName: 'photo[picture]',
    headers: {
      "X-CSRF-Token": $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    },
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    clickable: '#image-preview',
    previewsContainer: '#image-preview',
    thumbnailWidth: 200,
    thumbnailHeight: 200,
    parallelUploads: 100,
    autoProcessQueue: false,
    uploadMultiple: false
  });
  $('#item-submit').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    if (dropzone.getQueuedFiles().length > 0) {
      return dropzone.processQueue();
    } 
    else {
      return $('#dropform').submit();
    }

  });
  return dropzone.on('success', function(file, responseText) {
    return window.location.href = '/photos/' + responseText.id;
  });
  return dropzone.on('error', function(file, errorMessage, xhr) {
    console.log('error');
  });
});
```

**PhotosController**

```
def create
    @photo = current_user.photos.build(photo_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @photo.save!
        format.html { redirect_to @photo, notice: 'Photo was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @photo } 
      else
        format.html { redirect_to new_photos_path, notice: 'Photo was not created'}
        format.json { redirect_to photos_path and return @photo.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity } 
      end
    end  
  end
```

**edit**

```
return dropzone.on('error', function(file, errorMessage, xhr) {
  console.log('error');
  window.location.href = '/photos/new'
});
```

results in:

> Started POST "/photos" Processing by PhotosController#create as HTML
>   ...Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 422ms (ActiveRecord: 14.5ms)
>   ...method=GET path="/photos/new"...method=POST path="/photos"

and then we are back to the blank example.com/photos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
redirect_to new_photos_path
```

should be ->

```
redirect_to new_photo_path
```

Comment: Hi Timmy; your code-only answer would be more useful with some context. For example, you could explain why you think this code change is needed; and why it would fix the questioner's problem.